# Always adding two objects except of one to array (faulty if else)

Tags: ios, arrays, if-statement, tableview

I erased the code between the lines, because it's nothing special, just adding a contact to an array. I think it has to do with the brackets. So hopefully someone has a good eye and can tell me, why its always adding a contact two times :)

```
if ([string rangeOfString:@"00"].location == NSNotFound) {


    if(lastName && ([lastName length] > 0)) { 


        NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; 
        NSString *ccode = [prefs stringForKey:@"cc"];
        NSString *fileName = [prefs stringForKey:@"onumber"];

        NSString *str = number;
        NSString *newNumber = [str substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, [str length] - 1)];
        NSString *Nummer = [newNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

        NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://myserver/phpFile.php?number=%@%@&name=%@&lastname=%@", ccode, Nummer, firstName, lastName];
        NSString *webStringURL = [strURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:webStringURL]];
        NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    } 
    else {

        NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; 
        NSString *ccode = [prefs stringForKey:@"cc"];
        NSString *fileName = [prefs stringForKey:@"onumber"];

        NSString *str = number;
        NSString *newNumber = [str substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, [str length] - 1)];
        NSString *Nummer = [newNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

        NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://myserver/phpFile.php?number=%@%@&name=%@&lastname=""", ccode, Nummer, firstName];
        NSString *webStringURL = [strURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:webStringURL]];
        NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    }

} else if(lastName && ([lastName length] > 0)) { 

       NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; 
        NSString *ccode = [prefs stringForKey:@"cc"];
        NSString *fileName = [prefs stringForKey:@"onumber"];

        NSString *str = number;
        NSString *newNumber = [str substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, [str length] - 0)];
        NSString *Nummer = [newNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

        NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://myserver/phpFile.php?number=%@%@&name=%@&lastname=%@", ccode, Nummer, firstName, lastName];
        NSString *webStringURL = [strURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:webStringURL]];
        NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

} 
else {

       NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; 
        NSString *ccode = [prefs stringForKey:@"cc"];
        NSString *fileName = [prefs stringForKey:@"onumber"];

        NSString *str = number;
        NSString *newNumber = [str substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, [str length] - 0)];
        NSString *Nummer = [newNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

        NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://myserver/phpFile.php?number=%@%@&name=%@&lastname=""", ccode, Nummer, firstName];
        NSString *webStringURL = [strURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:webStringURL]];
        NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

}

if ([string rangeOfString:@"+"].location == NSNotFound) {

        if(lastName && ([lastName length] > 0)) { 

       NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; 
        NSString *ccode = [prefs stringForKey:@"cc"];
        NSString *fileName = [prefs stringForKey:@"onumber"];

        NSString *str = number;
        NSString *newNumber = [str substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, [str length] - 1)];
        NSString *Nummer = [newNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

        NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://myserver/phpFile.php?number=%@%@&name=%@&lastname=%@", ccode, Nummer, firstName, lastName];
        NSString *webStringURL = [strURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:webStringURL]];
        NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

                     } 
        else {

       NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; 
        NSString *ccode = [prefs stringForKey:@"cc"];
        NSString *fileName = [prefs stringForKey:@"onumber"];

        NSString *str = number;
        NSString *newNumber = [str substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, [str length] - 1)];
        NSString *Nummer = [newNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

        NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://myserver/phpFile.php?number=%@%@&name=%@&lastname=""", ccode, Nummer, firstName];
        NSString *webStringURL = [strURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:webStringURL]];
        NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        }

    } else if(lastName && ([lastName length] > 0)) { 

       NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; 
        NSString *ccode = [prefs stringForKey:@"cc"];
        NSString *fileName = [prefs stringForKey:@"onumber"];

        NSString *str = number;
        NSString *newNumber = [str substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(3, [str length] - 3)];
        NSString *Nummer = [newNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

        NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://myserver/phpFile.php?number=%@%@&name=%@&lastname=%@", ccode, Nummer, firstName, lastName];
        NSString *webStringURL = [strURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:webStringURL]];
        NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


} 
    else {

       NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; 
        NSString *ccode = [prefs stringForKey:@"cc"];
        NSString *fileName = [prefs stringForKey:@"onumber"];

        NSString *str = number;
        NSString *newNumber = [str substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(3, [str length] - 3)];
        NSString *Nummer = [newNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

        NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://myserver/phpFile.php?number=%@%@&name=%@&lastname=""", ccode, Nummer, firstName];
        NSString *webStringURL = [strURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:webStringURL]];
        NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`if ([string rangeOfString:@"+"].location == NSNotFound)` condition should start with else.

It should be as below:

```
else if ([string rangeOfString:@"+"].location == NSNotFound)
```

Also, before the second if line (mentioned below)

```
if ([string rangeOfString:@"+"].location == NSNotFound))
```

you should have closed '}' for first if.

Comment: Hey, that is what I thought too, but for some reason it gives numerous errors when adding an else before it.

Comment: Adding an `else` before the `if (it's got @"+" in it)` is an error because it is adding a second else clause to the `if (it's got @"00" in it)`.

Answer (score 1):

If some of the omitted code is executing twice, it's because the construction of your strings is such that two of your if statements are both true for the same string. Examine your strings, post the one that is being added twice. Does one of them have a `+` and `00` in it? But your bracketing is fine.

UPDATE
I guess I would start hunting this down by adding `NSLog()` statements to each of the `if/else` blocks to see when each is called. If you have a remote web service, the error could be there as well. In fact, it might be -- your obj-c code looks ok to me. Track GET requests at the server and add logging to `phpFile.php`.

Comment: No, they are cellphone numbers, I'm checking for the country code :) I updated it, as you can see the contacts get added to a database. But it always adds them twice.

Comment: Thanks I already did. This is why I thought my brackets are faulty, because it adds all contacts normally (once), except when they have a "00" or "+" in it. Then it adds the new string (without the "+" or "00") and the old one.